# Visual Studio 2017, dotnet core 2 публикация приложения в ubuntu

Tags: linux, visual-studio, .net-core

Приложение dotnet core2 в Visual Studio 2017, опубликовать одной кнопкой в linux и отладка возможно ли? Конечно в линуксе ssh настроен и установлен 
`dotnet  --version
2.1.4`

Comment: Расшарил папку через samba публикую туда, но хотелось бы еще запуск для отладки

Answer (score 0):

Настраиваем развертывание например через TFS используя cd/cd (pipeline) при слиянии с веткой Test. После публикации сможем подключится через SSH и заняться отладкой.